# Dapper conversion of TinyInt

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc-3, mvc-mini-profiler, dapper

I'm attempting to write my own DatabaseStorageBase for mini-profiler, and I'm running into issues in my

```
private List<T> LoadFor<T>(DbConnection conn, object idParameter)
```

method.  Dapper keeps yelling at me with

```
Error parsing column 5 (level=0 - SByte)
```

I'm storing level as `tinyint(4)`, so I'm assuming dapper cannot make the conversion from Tiny Int to what looks like an Enum (`ProfileLevel`)?  Could someone suggest how I should store the level in mysql so I can solve my conversion woes?

Comment: you don't need to inherit off the base, you can simply implement the storage interface

Comment: I've attempted to implement the storage interface, but the Save method still wants me to save the level.  Is there a way to get dapper to produce the enum from an integer value?  If not it looks like I'll have to just map it by hand.

Comment: @SamSaffron I forgot to tag you in my comment... my bad.

Comment: can you add a failing enum test to the dapper source so I can fix the enum issue?

Comment: @SamSaffron I think it needs to be pulling from MySql in order to error, so how should I construct the test?  I created a couple of enum tests that all worked in the dapper test harness, so I tried playing around more with the results coming back from c# in my project's solution.  If I don't cast to MiniProfiler (ie `connection.Query<MiniProfiler>(...)`) and instead do it dynamically (`var result = connection.Query(...)`, I can get the type successfully by doing `level = (MvcMiniProfiler.ProfileLevel)result.level`.  Even when I change the type to int in MySql, I get the error `level=0 - Int32`

Comment: ok I follow ... mysql enum support is bodge in the ado adapter ... hmmm, I am out next week, will chase it up the week after, can you add a ticket to the dapper bug tracker?

Comment: @SamSaffron [Here's a link to the bug I submitted](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/issues/detail?id=86).  I really do appreciate the time you're taking to help squash this bug :D

Answer (score 3):

Wow. what a cool insident, I'm also implement my own mysqlstorage for miniprofiler and get similar error with you.

miniprofiler uses enum as byte for MiniProfiler.Level and SqlTiming.ExecuteType
using tinyint datatype for this property return invalid cast which shown that it return Sbyte instead of byte. this behavior default behavior of mysql as it permit return of signed value of tinyint where as sqlserver not as mention here:

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?38,5524,5581#msg-5581

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/br/adonetefx/thread/8b0949ba-03e8-4637-baa1-d2b4ff0771f0

Therefore, the resolution is simply by alter the tinyint field of level and executeType into unsigned tinyint will return correct value (cast to byte). now my mysqlstorage working as expected.. hope can ask pull request to sam :)

Comment: I'll try this out over the weekend and post back with what happens, but it sounds like it could possibly be the solution to my problem :D